# AngularJS ng-show and $timeout not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and am doing an individual project in AngularJS using ng-show and if else statement with $timeout. However I cant get the the answers to timeout after a few seconds of being displayed. I tried may of combinations of this from current stackoverflow pages dealing with this subject and nothing. Everything else works but the timeout ability.

```
--HTML----
       <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>{{ question }}</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="myAnswer"><!--angular directive-->
          </div>

        </form>
            <div ng-show="myquestion(myAnswer)"> <!--angular directive-->
                <h5>{{ ansConf }}</h5><!-- if answer equals blue whale return string-->
            </div>
            <div ng-hide="myquestion(myAnswer)">
                <h5>{{ wrongAns }}</h5>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 odb" ng-init="whaleOne = 'assets/img/site/2560 8.jpg'" >
                <a href="#" ng-click="infoOne()"> <!--angular directive-->
                <img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" ng-src="{{ whaleOne }}"> <!--angular directive-->
            </a>
            </div>

--- AngularJS Code ---

var app = angular.module("bigBlue", []); /* New module called gamesite */

app.controller('whaleController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window, $timeout) { 

  $scope.question = 'Which whale is blue ?';
  $scope.rightAns = 'blue whale';
  $scope.wrongAns = 'nope';
  $scope.ansConf = 'Blue Whale is correct !';

  // setting value of the first question variable '' open string
  $scope.myAnswer = '';

  $scope.myquestion = function(myAnswer){
    if (myAnswer == $scope.rightAns){
      return true;
      $timeout(function () {
                $scope.myAnswer = false;
            }, 3000);
    }
    else if (myAnswer != $scope.rightAns){
      return false;
    }

  }
```

Comment: [read about return statement how it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Interrupt a function
>
> A function immediately stops at the point where return is called.

After return you timeout is never invoking, move it in the end

```
  if (myAnswer == $scope.rightAns){

      $timeout(function () {
                $scope.myAnswer = false;
            }, 3000);
     return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "whaleController", add the Dependency '$timeout' after '$window', like this:

```
app.controller('whaleController', ['$scope', '$window', '$timeout', function($scope, $window, $timeout) {
```

This way, it should work.

Comment: it's the return statement witch is issue not the $timeout

Comment: Accept the answer you found useful then.

Comment: Question the (if statement section)works fine however I would like the (else section to time out as well after the condition is met so it doesn't show for all time on the screen would i implemented the same suggestion but no progress.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace  `return true;` after  `$timeout`

Comment: Question the (if statement section)works fine however I would like the (else section to time out as well after the condition is met so it doesn't show for all time on the screen would i implemented the same suggestion but no progress

Comment: Did you try this ? I didn't gave u full code, I just Gave you the idea , what was wrong . 
Hope it helps u .