# AngularJS (ng-hide) $timeout not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had previously posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879362/angularjs-ng-show-and-timeout-not-working) trying to get ng-show to timeout. That solution works well. I have a new problem now, where I am having a problem with `ng-hide` else if statement. I tried implementing the same strategy and the `h5` heading stays visible continually even though I tell the text to timeout hide after 3000ms.

For example when someone types in the text box **'blue whale'** the **incorrect answer** disappears and shows **Blue Whale is correct!**'which is great but after 3 seconds the that disappears the text box is empty and below it show **incorrect answer**. This is the problem **incorrect answer** is staying seen not timing out after 3 seconds.

When implementing my current solution I get script errors as well on page.

HTML

```
       <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>{{ question }}</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="myAnswer"><!--angular directive-->
          </div>

        </form>
            <div ng-show="myquestion(myAnswer)"> <!--angular directive-->
                <h5>{{ ansConf }}</h5><!-- if answer equals blue whale return string-->
            </div>
            <div ng-hide="myquestion(myAnswer)">
                <h5>{{ wrongAns }}</h5>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 odb" ng-init="whaleOne = 'assets/img/site/2560 8.jpg'" >
                <a href="#" ng-click="infoOne()"> <!--angular directive-->
                <img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" ng-src="{{ whaleOne }}"> <!--angular directive-->
            </a>
            </div>
```

AngularJS Code

```
var app = angular.module("bigBlue", []); 

app.controller('whaleController', ['$scope', '$window', '$timeout', function($scope, $window, $timeout) { 

  $scope.question = 'Which whale is blue ?';
  $scope.rightAns = 'blue whale';
  $scope.wrongAns = 'nope';
  $scope.ansConf = 'Blue Whale is correct !';

  // setting value of the first question variable '' open string
  $scope.myAnswer = '';

   $scope.myquestion = function(myAnswer){

    if (myAnswer == $scope.rightAns){

      $timeout(function () {
                $scope.myAnswer = '';
            }, 3000);

      return true;
    }
    else if (myAnswer != $scope.rightAns) {
       $timeout(function () {
                $scope.myAnswer = '';
            }, 3000)
      return false;
    }
// in the else if statement i am trying to get the message (incorrect answer to disappear after 3 seconds and the text box to be blank)this is associated with ng-hide. 
  }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: A pop up in fire fox saying scripting error but that happens after about a minute.

Comment: you forgot `'$timeout'` in the array

Comment: Do you need to check the correctness of the answer each time the user modify the input ? because I think you should check that when the user click on a submit button for example rather than in a ng-show/ng-hide

Comment: if your timeout is always the same, and the flow is always the same, why not do this with css? have an element appear with `ng-if`, `ng-show`, or `ng-hide`, and the class on that element, should have an animation to change opacity to 0. with the `animation-delay` property, you can decide how long the element will show before it disappears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS ng-show and $timeout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879362/angularjs-ng-show-and-timeout-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.controller('whaleController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window, $timeout) {
```

You forgotten $timeout

```
app.controller('whaleController', ['$scope', '$window', '$timeout', function($scope, $window, $timeout) {
```

It generate a loop, add a condition:

```
$scope.myquestion = function (myAnswer) {
    if (myAnswer) {
        if (myAnswer == $scope.rightAns) {

            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.myAnswer = '';
            }, 3000);

            return true;
        }
        else if (myAnswer != $scope.rightAns) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.myAnswer = '';
            }, 3000)
            return false;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

See if you want this:

```
    <div ng-show="myquestion(myAnswer) && myAnswer">
        <h5>{{ ansConf }}</h5>
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="myquestion(myAnswer) || !myAnswer">
        <h5>{{ wrongAns }}</h5>
    </div>
```

Comment: I actually currently have that  in my controller but i did not post it sorry but it does look like this app.controller('whaleController', ['$scope', '$window', '$timeout', function($scope, $window, $timeout)

Comment: Thanks I will try that solution. To clarify my issue i added more info to describe the problem

Comment: Okay this works but there is still a slight issue. (First what is working when I type blue whale it give the message 'blue whale is correct' that disappears after 3 seconds and if i type in the wrong answer that disappears after 3 seconds). However the <h5> {{ wrongAns }} <H5> which equals text (incorrect information) underneath the text box still dose not disappear after 3 seconds of being displayed which is the problem.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Okay i will try to clarify and thank you for helping me i really appreciate it. Okay everything else is working. The part that is not working is that when the text box is empty it shows the <h5> incorrect answer <h5> as long as the box is empty. I want this to disappear after 3 seconds. its not doing that

Comment: THAT WORKED! Thank you so much. I would never have thought of that.

Comment: Thank you. Could you vote my answer? This is important in stackoverflow.